# how to use `url` template tag in `with` template tag in django templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

i have html component that i want to include in my template that has a link as below

```
<a href="{{url_name}}" ........
```

in my template i am trying to pass the `url_name` using the `with` tag

```
    {% include 'components/buttons/_add_button.html' with url_name="{% url 'equipments:equipment-add' %}" reference_name='equipment' %}
```

this seems not to work as i get the following error

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'
```

## **this works though**

using the hardcoded url works however i wanted to implement this using url names for flexibility

```
    {% include 'components/buttons/_add_button.html' with url_name="equipments/equipment/add" reference_name='equipment' %}
```

***urls.py***

```
app_name = "equipments"
 ....

  path("equipment/add/",views.EquipmentCreateView.as_view(), name="equipment-add",
    ),
...
```

can i use a custom tag to pass this url name to my component template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a custom filter in Django as:

```
@register.filter
def get_url(url_name):
    return reverse(url_name)
```

I now pass the `url_name` in my template as:

```
{% include 'components/buttons/_add_button.html' with url_name="equipments:equipment-add" reference_name='equipment' %}
```

Then in my Html component I use:

```
<a href="{{url_name|get_url}}"...
```